550-No Such User Here 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command))
I have searched and searched and searched on the net and I can't find a solution to debug this definitive SMTP installation. So, I'd like you to help me please.
1. First of all, I have a problem where the mails I try to send to my customers on GMAIL go to SPAM. Of course I have set up spf, DKIM, dmarc but nothing works and my mails always go to SPAM. So, can you help me to fix this issue for me please?
Here's how I set up spf:
| Type  | Host                   | Value          | TTL    |
|-------|------------------------|----------------|--------|
| TXT RE| goshareit.co           | v=spf1 ip4:replace_by_ip_server_vps a mx ~all| Automatic |

Here's how I configured dkim:
| Type  | Host                   | Value          | TTL    |
|-------|------------------------|----------------|--------|
| TXT RE| mail._domainkey        | v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; p=YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY| Automatic |

Here's how I configured dmarc:

| Type  | Host                   | Value          | TTL    |
|-------|------------------------|----------------|--------|
| TXT RE| _dmarc   | `v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; aspf=r; sp=none`| Automatic |

2. Secondly, when I try to send an email to a professional email, it doesn't arrive at its destination (the professional email) and I don't know why?
Here how i was set up the Postfix configuration file "sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf":
# Basic settings
myhostname = replace_by_my_domain_name
myorigin = replace_by_my_domain_name
mydomain = replace_by_my_domain_name
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain

# Relay settings (if needed, but can be empty for direct delivery)
relayhost =

# TLS settings for secure email transfer
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/replace_by_my_domain_name/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/replace_by_my_domain_name/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes

# Enable SMTP authentication using Dovecot
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes

# SMTP recipient restrictions (control who can send emails)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination

# Mailbox size limit (set to 0 for unlimited size)
mailbox_size_limit = 0

# Enable queue for mail
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/sbin
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

# Security settings
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 3.6

# Limit to localhost for relay (if no relay host is set)
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
home_mailbox= Maildir/

After that, I run this command:
 sudo postconf -e 'home_mailbox = Maildir\'

Then I have update sudo nano /etc/hosts file to set up the host and add this:
127.0.0.1 localhost ubuntu.local ubuntu
127.0.0.1 replace_by_my_domain_name my_website_name
152.53.55.237 replace_by_my_domain_name

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

And then, I Update the file sudo nano /etc/postfix/master.cf and add this block code so that we can use
Roundcube not to cause this error SMTP Error (): Authentication failed
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject

and finally I restart postfix.
sudo systemctl restart postfix

And after that, I tried to send emails to this company support@transladocs.com in my vps terminal server like this and it doesn't work:
echo "This is a test email" | mail -s "Test Email" support@transladocs.com

And when I check the errors by doing this sudo tail -f /var/log/mail.log it shows me this error 550-No Such User Here 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command)).
Here's the errors with some details:
root@goshareit:/var/www# echo "This is a test email" | mail -s "Test Email" support@transladocs.com root@goshareit:/var/www# tail -f /var/log/mail.log                                                                              2024-10-18T05:23:22.729801+02:00 goshareit postfix/pickup[1749]: B208EA6BD9: uid=0 from=<root@goshareit.co> 2024-10-18T05:23:22.737760+02:00 goshareit postfix/cleanup[2614]: B208EA6BD9: message-id=<20241018032322.B208EA6BD9@goshareit.co>                                                                                       2024-10-18T05:23:22.753331+02:00 goshareit postfix/qmgr[1750]: B208EA6BD9: from=<root@goshareit.co>, size=348, nrcpt=1 (queue active)                                                2024-10-18T05:23:23.482248+02:00 goshareit postfix/smtp[2616]: B208EA6BD9: to=<support@transladocs.com>, relay=_dc-mx.50e0a8e24d73.transladocs.com[65.181.111.251]:25, delay=0.76, delays=0.04/0.01/0.65/0.06, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host _dc-mx.50e0a8e24d73.transladocs.com[65.181.111.251] said: 550-Verification failed for <root@goshareit.co> 550-No Such User Here 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command))             2024-10-18T05:23:23.501725+02:00 goshareit postfix/cleanup[2614]: 7A3AEA6BDA: message-id=<20241018032323.7A3AEA6BDA@goshareit.co>                                                                                       2024-10-18T05:23:23.512471+02:00 goshareit postfix/bounce[2617]: B208EA6BD9: sender non-delivery notification: 7A3AEA6BDA       2024-10-18T05:23:23.512598+02:00 goshareit postfix/qmgr[1750]: 7A3AEA6BDA: from=<>, size=2491, nrcpt=1 (queue active) 2024-10-18T05:23:23.512860+02:00 goshareit postfix/qmgr[1750]: B208EA6BD9: removed                                              2024-10-18T05:23:23.526177+02:00 goshareit postfix/local[2618]: 7A3AEA6BDA: to=<root@goshareit.co>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)                                                            2024-10-18T05:23:23.526319+02:00 goshareit postfix/qmgr[1750]: 7A3AEA6BDA: removed
However, it worked fine when I sent emails to GMAIL, YAHOO but the problem they end up in SPAMS from these people.
So, what should I do in this case?
Don't forget that the richardson user does exist on the server. And I've noticed when I do this sudo hostnamectl set-hostname goshareit rather than sudo hostnamectl set-hostname goshareit.co and then I send it, the email goes correctly. But the problem, it doesn't have the dot "." in the email, it displays like this richardson@goshareit. What should I do in this case? and how can I please solve these two big problems I'm facing right now? And please, this has gone on too long???

Have you implemented all of the requirements, mentioned at https://support.google.com/a/answer/81126?sjid=699798412048624296-EU#zippy=%2Crequirements-for-all-senders
What subsystem implements DKIM?

@M. Behrens I was use this system sudo apt install -y opendkim opendkim-tools cd /etc/opendkim/keys/goshareit.co sudo opendkim-genkey -t -s default -d goshareit.co

I cannot find any milter configuration for OpenDKIM in main.cf.

What can you suggest me to do?

Implement milter as described at https://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html in your test environment.
